# Giving input parameters to cpp file through browser and getting output on browser using Php

Tags: php

I am running a **CPP file** on the browser using PHP.
when the CPP file is executed, it requires some input parameters.
The First parameter is given, the corresponding output is displayed  and then the page is refreshed and after refresh, the second parameter is given and then final output comes.After that Program is terminated.

**Here is the Code for first input:**

```
<?php
$a=$_GET['players'];
echo '<pre>';
$last_line = exec('C:\Users\Kartik\Documents\programmes\hack.exe $a');
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
?>
```

**The Problem is** when the code is executed,It is accepting the first input and giving the corresponding output but after that, the page is **not refreshed** and the second input is **not accepted**.

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quotes `"` to evaluate php variable `$a`

```
<?php
  $a = $_GET["players"];
  echo "<pre>";
  $last_line = exec("C:\Users\Kartik\Documents\programmes\hack.exe $a");
  echo "</pre> <hr />Last line of the output: $last_line";
?>
```

Comment: I am getting the value of last_line for the first input.But then I want the page should be refreshed and then I should give the second input.

Comment: you want page reloading ?

Comment: Yes, after the first output is displayed the page should be reloaded and then second input is given.

Comment: Is reloading page with updated param is not working you tried this ?